# Html pattern password characters and numbers

Tags: html, design-patterns

The password must be at least 8 and no more than 16 characters long and consist of alphanumeric characters.  There must be at least two non-successive characters of each of the types:  alphabetic and digit.  This  means: some letters are separated by some digits and some digits are separated by some letters.

I need to write an html pattern using regular expressions. How do i write this pattern using the regular expressions?

Comment: What is the question you are actually asking here?

Comment: What do you mean? You've tagged only HTML. Which language is supposed to be used by you? Additionally to say, [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: It sounds me that the question is about using the HTML5 `pattern` attribute for checking an input field.

Answer (score 2):

The words “Html pattern” in the heading (though nothing in the message body) suggest that the question is how to express a condition in the `pattern` attribute in an `input type=password` attribute in HTML.

The condition in the first sentence is simple: assuming we restrict ourselves to Ascii characters, the attribute would be `pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{8,16}"`.

The complexity added in the second sentence appears to be one that cannot be expressed as a regular expression. And the `pattern` attribute is by definition limited to regular expressions.

Comment: Yes you are right that i have to use the pattern attribute but how do make the second sentence work in the pattern. I can only use regular expression to make it work. The complexity in the second sentence is the hard part.